# Relation between countable set and finite

Tags: real-analysis

If there exists a bijection $f$ between a set $S$ and the natural numbers, then the set is called countable.
If there is no one-to-one function $f$ from $S$ to the natural numbers, then the set is called finite.

Intuitively speaking, I thought finite sets and countable sets are the same. Because a finite set is countable (based on common sense) and also a countable set is finite. But if I judge from the definition, it seems that this is not the case.

Comment: The definition of finite here is badly broken. It would make the set of real numbers finite.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen:mind to elaborate?

Comment: @Harald: I'm pretty sure you were correct. The OP asserted that a set is finite if there is *no* injection $S \to \mathbb{N}$, which is false. And, indeed, there is no injection $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{N}$. What the OP has called finite is what most people call uncountable!

Comment: @Clive: Argh. You're right. Two misreadings in half an hour? Your honour, I can only plead a shortage of caffeine. It's early morning, and I am preoccupied with a lecture that I need to prepare. (I removed my second, erroneous, comment. My apologies if this messes up the thread.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two common usages of the word *countable*:

1. A set $X$ is countable if there is an injection $X \to \mathbb{N}$
2. A set $X$ is countable if there is a bijection $X \to \mathbb{N}$

These definitions are not equivalent, since (1) tells you that finite sets are countable but (2) tells you that they are not.

Many authors distinguish between the two by referring to (2) as *countably infinite*, but there are some who use *countable* exclusively to refer to infinite sets.

Comment: And 1 is equivalent to the existence of a surjection $\mathbb{N}\to X$. Personally, I prefer 1 over 2, which I find somewhat perverse. But we'll have to live with some perversity.

Answer (score 0):

Countable here refers to infinite counting, not just finite. Note that you can count the elements of $\mathbb{N}$, though it may take infinite time; the bijection in the definition gives a scheme for counting. On the other hand you have no such scheme for counting the elements of $\mathbb{R}.$